# How do I perform a guard impact?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

In the previous Soulcalibur games, guard impacting was performed by pressing `▷G` (forward and guard; `6G`, in fighting game direction terminology).

In Soulcalibur V, this was removed. Guard impact still exists, but it uses the soul gauge, and apparently requires a different combination (likely involving `A+B+K`, since it uses the soul gauge). What is that combination?

Comment: My guess is they are some special combo, that when hit at the right time they do. I remember in the 4 thats sometimes your weapon glowed green while doing combos, and if a player hit the green weapon a guard impact

Comment: Is it not in the manual? Do games have manuals any more?

Comment: @StrixVaria I just picked this up for X360 yesterday and it did come with the manual, as well as this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guard impacts are performed with the combination `◁A+B+K` (`4A+B+K`) and takes half of a soul gauge meter, regardless of whether or not they hit.

Additionally, certain characters have combinations that perform a guard impact. For example, Siegfried's `B+K` stance transition includes a guard impact. You'll be able to recognize these by their green glow as the animation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In scV there is also a "just guard", performed by tapping block extremely close to when the opponent strikes as well as the aforementioned "guard impact", which is the only special guard that takes up 25% special meter.